# How to store data and install softwares in Amazon Web Services (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS. I want to create an AMI with all of my required installed packages. It will not take more than 15 GB, I guess. So,I should launch an instance with root storage around 20GB and then take a snapshot of it from which I can launch an instance at any point of time. Right?
Now, later on, suppose I have attach suppose 300GB for data analysis only (not for long term storage) with my AMI. And, then install some software packages again, then where it will be stored : the root device (20GB) or the 300GB EBS storage? If I just delete the 300GB storage everytime after my data analysis, will all the packages remain stored in my AMI?

Thanks,
Deep

Answer (score 2):

Deep the packages you stored during snapshot will remain there.
But the VM you spun up from the template will have 300GB EBS mounted if you choose to do so. You can set some configuration at the EBS level to keep it or delete it when you terminate the VM.

If your intent is to store the results within the VM and shut down VM, I would recommend to take another snapshot or back it up.

If you don’t want the summarised or processed results stored or backed up, you should be able to just used previous snapshot image, to spin up another one if you need.

Answer (score 2):

An AMI is a point in time snapshot of your EBS device (hard drive/ssd/what have you) that can be used to launch other duplicate devices from the same configuration. If you install additional dependencies on a deployed EBS, delete that EBS, and then restore from the same AMI, it will only have what was originally on it when you created the AMI.

If you want to keep dependencies updated on an AMI, you'll need to create a new snapshot of the root EBS device and create another AMI from that snapshot. AMIs are immutable and cannot be modified after the fact.

Comment: Hi @scgrk, thanks for your answer. Two more questions:  1.Where the new dependencies are stored: the root volume or the attached EBS storage?  2. How can I keep all my data (for analysis only; not long term storage) in the 300GB EBS storage so that I can remove them after my analysis?  Thanks

Comment: I think you have a misconception of what volumes for an EC2 are. If you have 2 hard drives, one with your operating system and one for everything else, and you install a program on the hard drive with your operating system, where are the dependencies? EBS is a virtual hard drive. You can take an EBS out of one EC2 and put it into another and it works fine. Or you can create a backup of the EBS and put it in another EC2. Or you can create a bootable disk from your hard drive and store it as an AMI.